# Does this setup of database tables look right?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I supposed to create these two tables in mySQL

[image]

What does not make sense to me is that how the Users table works with the FriendsXRef.
I know what cross reference tables are, but, in this case I do not see the logic in terms of the following. 
I am asked to inset the following data into the user table:

> Helen X. World, Born January 5, 1995, Female, Friend of Helen Y. World
>
> Helen Y. World, Born November 24, 1999, Female, Friend of Alicia R.
>   Sayers, Helen X. World, and Mark U. Plank
>
> Alicia R. Sayers, Born July 22, 1990, Female, Friend of Helen Y. World
>   and Mark U. Plank
>
> Mark U. Plank, Born March 15, 1998, Male, Friend of Helen Y. World,
>   Alicia R. Sayers and Walt Z. Plank
>
> Walt Z. Plank, Born May 10, 1989, Male, Friend of Mark U. Plan

This is what I did:

```
insert into users values(1, 'Helen', 'World', 'X', 'F', '1995-01-05');
insert into users values(2, 'Helen', 'World', 'Y', 'F', '1999-11-24');
insert into users values(3, 'Alicia', 'Sayers', 'R', 'F', '1990-07-20');
insert into users values(4, 'Mark', 'Plank', 'U', 'M', '1998-03-15');
insert into users values(5, 'Walt', 'Plank', 'Z', 'M', '1989-05-10');
```

As you see, I need to figure out how to insert data into the **FriendsXref** table so that it shows that lets say for the first part, Helen Y World is Helen X World's friend.

When I try to do the add the add to the **FriendsXref** table like this:

```
insert into friendsxref values(2, 1);

insert into friendsxref values(3, 2);
insert into friendsxref values(1, 2);
insert into friendsxref values(4, 2);

insert into friendsxref values(2, 3);
insert into friendsxref values(4, 3);

insert into friendsxref values(2,4);
insert into friendsxref values(3,4);
insert into friendsxref values(5,4);

insert into friendsxref values(4,5);
```

I obviously get an error, because the UserID field of the **FriendsXref** table is set to be unique.

Then, my question is, how does this work? How can I add those friend into to the **FriendsXref**  table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could set a separate row identifier for the `FriendsXref` table. The table can have columns `id(Primary key)`, `UserID(Foreign key)`, `FriendID`.
In this way you won't get the any error since you already have a unnique row identifier in the `id` column.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple:** Make both columns unique at the same time. It only get errors when you make the same people as friend twice.

```
ALTER TABLE `FriendsXref` ADD UNIQUE( `UserID`, `FriendID`);
```